# How to return the col type of a R tibble in compact string representation?

Tags: r, tibble

For example I have a tibble like this.
test <- tibble(a = 10, b = "a")

with this input, I want a function that can return "dc" which represent double and character.

The reason I ask this is that I want to read in lots of files. and I don't want to let read_table function to decide the type for each columns. I can specific the string manually, but since the actually data I want to import have 50 columns, it is quite hard to do manually.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `test %>% summarise_all(class)` or as function `dc <- function(dat) dat %>% summarise_all(class); dc(test)`

Comment: This `paste0(sapply(test, function(x) substr(class(x), 1, 1)), collapse = "")` ?

Comment: I would say that by creating a single string with only the first letter can be a bit difficult to identity when there are 100s of columns.  Instead, using `summarise_all(class)` gets the class of the columns.  If we want to identify the subset of columns say numeric, use `select_if(is.numeric)`

Comment: What should happen if your tibble contains a column of complex numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the aforementioned `test %>% summarise_all(class)` will give you the class names of the columns it does so in a long form, whereas in this problem you to convert them to single character codes that mean something to `read_table` `col_types`. To map from class names to single letter codes you can use a lookup table, here's an (incomplete) example with `dput`:

```
structure(list(col_type = c("character", "integer", "numeric", 
"double", "logical"), code = c("c", "i", "n", "d", "l")), .Names = c("col_type", 
"code"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Now using this table, I'll call it `types`, we can finally transform the column types in a single string:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

test %>% 
  summarise_all(class) %>% 
  gather(col_name, col_type) %>% 
  left_join(types) %>% 
  summarise(col_types = str_c(code, collapse = "")) %>% 
  unlist(use.names = FALSE)
```

This gets the class for each column (`summarise_all`) then gathers them into a tibble matching the column name with the column type (`gather`). The `left_join` matches on the `col_type` column and gives the short 1-char code for each column name. Now we don't do anything with the column names, so it's fine to just concatenate with a `summarise` and `str_c`. Finally `unlist` pulls the string out of a tibble.

Comment: Thank you. This work. May I ask what "row.names = c(NA, -5L)" means here?

Comment: I'm not sure about `row.names = c(NA, -5L)` but what `dput` does is gives you a textual representation of an R object. This means the output which I provided can be copy-pasted into your R code to recreate the dataframe used in the example code later. Try pasting it into your R console and you'll see you get a dataframe. I'm guessing `row.names = c(NA, -5L)` refers to the fact there are 5 unnamed rows.

Comment: A compact proposal from: https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/274

    `iris %>% 
        dplyr::summarise_all(class) %>% 
        tidyr::gather(variable, class)`

Answer (score 0):

```
test <- tibble(a = 10, b = "a")

test %>% purrr::map_chr(pillar::type_sum) %>% paste(collapse = "_")
# "dbl_chr"
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

References:
https://tibble.tidyverse.org/articles/types.html
current dplyr version: ‘1.0.9’.

Thank you all for your input. I wanted to update the answer to include more column types and to avoid superseded dplyr version functions.

col_types argument in readr packages has some more types than those mentioned in the answers above:

```
types <-structure(list(code = c("c", "i", "d", "l", "f", "D", "T", "t"), 
                      col_type = c("chr", "int", "dbl", "lgl", "fct", "date", "dttm", "time")),
                 class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

I removed the guess and skip options.

Using the `pillar::type_sum()`functions returns the same column abbreviations that are used in tibble package. so

```
test |> 
    summarise(across(everything(), pillar::type_sum)) |> 
    pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "col_names", values_to = "col_type") |> 
    left_join(types) |> 
    pull(code) |> 
    str_c(collapse = "")
```

This returns a character vector, that could be used as an argument, while using the readr package. This is useful when reading and appending multiple csvs, and you want to force the column types, to avoid `bind_rows()` throwing an error.

So running `map_dfr(all_csv_paths, read_csv)` would not depend on correct guessing of column types.